# Using Click Event on Layer A to query Layer B in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have two polygon layers in a webmap service and want to do a dynamic query on click, such that when the user clicks on a lake (layer A) with ID = 100, the corresponding watershed boundary (layer B) with ID = 100 is highlighted. So basically, I want to pass the ID found on click from layer A and use that ID to query layer B by attribute. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure a [Query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html#geometry) to run based on the geometry of the mouse click
2. Configure a [Query Task](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/querytask-amd.html) on Layer A, using the query from above
3. In the callback for the query task, obtain the ID of the lake
4. Run a second query task on Layer B, using a second query which uses a [where clause](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html#where) based on the ID of the lake

The sample [query data without a map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_nomap.html) shows how to run an attribute query, while [manage results from multiple queries](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_deferred_list.html) shows how to run a query task, albeit in a slightly complicated manner.